# Compiling libnoise on windows with mingw

Tags: c++, mingw

This is my first post here so forgive me if I've done something wrong.

I've been struggling with this for a few days and I've finally decided to concede and ask for help. Put simply, I would like to compile libnoise (1.0.0) on windows using mingw. However, there seems to be a lack of information available online.

I have downloaded the source files from the website and followed the instructions inside the INSTALL text file which indicate that I should run the command "CXXFLAGS='-O3 -fomit-frame-pointer' make" (which I do from the mingW shell).

The output from this operation can be found at [link](http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=EOAE7) (I've linked rather then posting the output due to its length). The output doesn't vary much if I omit the CXXFLAGS or the fomit-frame-pointer flags or if I use the mingw32-make or make all commands.

It seems to be complaining about missing files such as

> Makefile:56: ../src/latlon.d: No such file or directory

though I can confirm they exist in the directory stated. It is also complaining about something else

> c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):main.c:(.tex
>   t.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `_WinMain@16' collect2.exe:
>   error: ld returned 1 exit status make[1]: *** [libnoise.so.0.3] Error
>   1 make[1]: Leaving directory`
>   /c/users/gibbons/desktop/libnoisesrc-1.0.0/noise/src ' make: ***
>   [src] Error 2

I have no idea how to address these issues. A google search didn't really turn up much other then a single blog [post](http://kbokonseriousstuff.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/libnoise-mingw-builds.html).  Which also didn't really help since I am unsure what it means by "Rename the library name to give it a proper DLL extension. A replace-all will do.".

Any help or advice would be appreciated, I'm really quite stuck! :-/

Cheers

Extra info: I'm running windows 7, 64 bit and (think) I'm on mingW 4.7.0.

Comment: I don't know if you ever solved this issue, but if you haven't, user Lukas put together a CMake setup that makes building libnoise very easy. You can find it linked in his answer, to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272971/netbeans-c-using-mingw-and-the-libnoise-library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't worry about `No such file or directory`. It's normal, see the bottom of `src/Makefile` for explanation.
2. Don't ever use target `clean`. I couldn't recover from that.
3. **Remove all directions to build `.so` files**. These are linux files and cannot be built by mingw. Open all the `Makefile`s and comment out lines containing `.so`, except the lines:

   `libnoise: libnoise.so libnoise.a libnoise.la`
   `all: libnoise.a libnoise.la libnoise.so.0.3`

   In the above lines only remove the words containing `.so`. This will prevent building `.so` targets.

Find the **static library** in `src/.libs/libnoise.a`.

**Building DLL** would be a bit harder, as the authors build it using Visual Studio. There are no makefile targets to build the dll. One would need to prepare a few more lines to process files in `win32` directory and produce the library out of it.

Comment: You, sir, are a legend. Thankyou very, very much! I've not tested it yet but it appears to have worked! :)

Comment: The files in the `win32` directory are mainly of cosmetic nature. They add some additional information to the DLL. Since to me the Makefile seemed quite broken, I've written a CMake script and adjusted the directory structure, but the code itself is still the same. It's now easy to build a static or a shared library: [GitHub Project](https://github.com/eXpl0it3r/libnoise)