# Libnoise don't want to compile: Cannot find -lnoise

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw, noise

I'm trying to use the `Libnoise` library and I keep get this error:

```
F:\PortableApps\Documents\Adventure³>g++ Compiled/*.o -o Adventure3 -L./Libs -static -lglew32 -lglfw3dll -lopengl32 -lfreetype -lnoise -static-libgcc-static-libstdc++ Resources/icon.res
f:/portableapps/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lnoise
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have the `libnoise.lib` in my `Libs` folder. I tried with `-llibnoise` instead, and I get:

```
F:\PortableApps\Documents\Adventure³>g++ Compiled/*.o -o Adventure3  -L./Libs -static -lglew32 -lglfw3dll -lopengl32 -lfreetype -llibnoise -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ Resources/icon.res
Compiled/Generator.o:Generator.cpp:(.text+0x3d): undefined reference to `noise::module::Perlin::GetValue(double, double, double) const'
Compiled/Generator.o:Generator.cpp:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `noise::module::Perlin::Perlin()'
Compiled/Generator.o:Generator.cpp:(.text$_ZN5noise6module6PerlinD1Ev[__ZN5noise6module6PerlinD1Ev]+0xa): undefined reference to `vtable for noise::module::Perlin'
Compiled/Generator.o:Generator.cpp:(.text$_ZN5noise6module6PerlinD1Ev[__ZN5noise6module6PerlinD1Ev]+0x19): undefined reference to `noise::module::Module::~Module()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't know how to manually compile the source, it always return me a `WinMain@16` error, no matter what I try to `make`.

Now, I really don't know what to do...

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-l` option of gcc supposes that library got name starting with `lib`, so `-lnoise` would link libnoise.

Usually .lib is a n import library  or static library. The problems related to import libraries  described here: [How do import libraries work and why doesn't MinGW need them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27824102/how-do-import-libraries-work-and-why-doesnt-mingw-need-them)

In relation to libnoise: [Netbeans C++ using MinGW and the libnoise library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15272971/netbeans-c-using-mingw-and-the-libnoise-library)

Comment: @Trytio also how you linked it? is it in format compatible to your compiler?

Comment: I didn't know that lib have specific format. How can I know the format?

Comment: Ok, I finally found how to compile with the link that you gave me. Unfortunately, I still have the second message error when i do `-lnoise`...

Comment: I found the problem, it is because I can't compile .so with mingw.